# typescript narrowing not working for truthiness with nested function

Tags: typescript, narrowing

In the shared code ([Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.4&ssl=11&ssc=12&pln=1&pc=1#code/DYUwLgBAbgliDuIBOAuCBvCBrEBPNAzmEjAHYDmEAvhAD4SkCuwwA3AFDsBmjpAxmBgB7UhDBCADgBkAhrmQAKAJQZ2ECDC4QFAQlgJkKpOEZJSHdT36CREY12MEAFstXr1fEQSGgAdMCFyBX1EJF8cXCULajU7EAcQZ2UOKk5xaTlFKKA)) compiler is throwing an error `Object is possibly 'null'.`

Is there any case possible where `refresh` can be called so that `viewer` can be null provided there is an early return when `viewer` is null in the `topLayer` function?

If not what could be the reason typescript does not narrow this in case of nested function?

Answer (score 2):

Here is somewhat close but obviously not the same and highly contrived example:

```ts
declare var viewer: { key: string } | null;

let _viewer = { key: 'key' } as { key: string } | null

Object.defineProperty(window, 'viewer', {
  get() {
    const val = _viewer;
    _viewer = null;
    return val
  }
})

function topLayer() {
  if (!viewer) return;
  function refresh() {
    console.log(viewer.key); // shows `Cannot read property 'key' of null` error
  }
  refresh();
}

topLayer();
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wXR3Dm)

Though in fact typescript uses some heuristics to narrow types but obviously doesn't run your program with all possible values of `viewer` variable. New function `refresh` creates new scope for `viewer` free (not a local variable and not a parameter) variable where it's still not narrowed.

If you rewrite it as:

```ts
function topLayer() {
  if (!viewer) return;
  function refresh(viewer: { key: string }) {
    console.log(viewer.key);
  }
  refresh(viewer);
}
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wOaMEm)

Everything works as expected.

Comment: I knew we can use the latter one or `console.log((viewer as { key: string }).key);`, which I am currently using,  I actually kinda wanted to avoid these.

Comment: Also, the example you shared for where `viewer.key` could break, I get the idea thanks for the eg., but if we think the only case it can break is if the reference to the original variable changes, just wondering does ts track such type of variables separately, and can this be narrowed if the variable in the closure is const   @aleksxor

Comment: My second code snippet doesn't use type assertion. That's valid typescript type narrowing. If you remove the conditional check it will fail. While type assertions will work like nothing happened.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense, did not consider that, since in my case it's impossible to get rid of it, it's a JWT that needs to be passed in a network call.